# In Excel how do I format cells correctly to work with the following date/time format?

Tags: excel, datetime

Could someone please tell me what cell format I should use to format the following so that they are recognised in a date time format I can then use to sort from oldest date to newest date please?

```
02-DEC-21 21.32.01.666000000
02-DEC-21 22.16.50.588000000
03-DEC-21 00.31.06.414000000
03-DEC-21 03.50.11.644000000
03-OCT-21 18.04.41.267000000
04-DEC-21 05.39.27.832000000
```

I’ve tried using dd-mmm-yy hh.mm.ss.000 (can’t enter more than three 0’s in milliseconds) and also without the .000 at the end but the cells don’t get recognised as dates when I try and sort them

Thanks

Comment: They are true date on excel cell or just string?

Comment: They are currently in 'General' cell format so guess they are just strings currently. I thought using a format similar to this dd-mmm-yy hh.mm.ss. would tell Excel to treat it as a date/time.

Comment: more like `DD-MMM-YY hh.mm.ss.000`? See also [Format a date the way you want](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e)

Comment: @Reck Dates in Excel are stored as a binary value in the OADate format (a decimal). That's why you often see decimals instead of dates in some Excel sheets. How the dates are shown depends entirely on the cell style. That style doesn't affect sorting or filtering. If you ensure dates are actually stored as dates instead of text, you won't have sorting problems. Just make sure the cell style is set the way you want

Comment: How are the dates entered? That's when mistakes are made, when users enter strings that may not match the cell's date style or the user's locale. When a date is entered manually Excel will parse it based on the style and locale and store an OADate. If you try to force the format you *increase* the chances of bad values or raw text instead of dates

Comment: The data comes in to the spreadsheet via a database query so I have no choice in the initial way that it's stored. So I suppose the question is how I can convert this to a date time format I can use to sort and filter by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two formulas to retrieve the date part and the time part.
I named the range with the dates `DateColumn`

To retrieve the date part: `=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(DateColumn,9),".",":"))`

To retrieve the time part: `=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(DateColumn,11,8),".",":"))`

To retrieve the whole date incl. time:
`=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(DateColumn,9),".",":")) + TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(DateColumn,11,8),".",":"))`

These formulas return a number, e.g. 44532 for 02-DEC-21 or 0,92835648 for 22.16.50 or 44532,92835648 for the whole date with time. You have to format them accordingly.

But be aware: this will only work on an english system.
E.g. on a German system only *Dez* or *Okt* would get recognized.

Comment: Thanks for that formula. I've tested it out against one of the date strings by putting one formula in the cell next to it and the time formula in the next one. I replaced the range with the actual cell and then I could drag down.

So I now have two extra columns but the date and time are seperate. What's the best way to combine them back into a single column?

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to sum both values.

Comment: Thanks Ike, this is looking good.